# SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN / NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on mismatched site

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, ssl, hsts

I am having a problem where sporadically, I start getting SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN errors in Firefox and NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID errors in Chrome on the same sites (so it must be something they share in common, rather than within the browsers themselves). Most commonly, the problem happens at mail.google.com, but the bizarre part is that when I click the error screen for more details, it indicates that the problem is for a washingtonpost.com certificate. Here's the text of the error from Firefox:

> Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for mail.google.com. The certificate is only valid for the following names: [www.washingtonpost.com](http://www.washingtonpost.com), washingtonpost.com, subscribe.washingtonpost.com, live.washingtonpost.com, apps.washingtonpost.com, js.washingtonpost.com, css.washingtonpost.com, img.washingtonpost.com, img2.washingtonpost.com, img3.washingtonpost.com
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I have tried going into Windows Internet Options / Content and clicking Clear SSL State, but it is unclear if this helps. It didn't fix the problem, so I tried rebooting after that, and it helped; but then the problem comes back a few days later. So far, it the certificates that it has claimed are invalid are always washingtonpost.com certificates, but the error is always on other sites (and often multiple other sites).

Any idea what's going on here, or how I might permanently clear it up?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the certificate details for a website that is generating this error.

Comment: I don't have one at the moment, but will happily post one the next time the error happens. Sporadic errors are frustrating that way.

Comment: Can’t you just go to the same website that generated the error the first time?

Comment: No, that's the frustrating part about it. When it goes sour, mail.google.com gives the error posted above, on a washingtonpost.com certificate. I cleared it up by clearing SSL State and rebooting. mail.google.com and washingtonpost.com both work fine now. It'll probably pop back up again in a few days.

Comment: Any plugins or add-ons doing funny stuff? The browser obviously thinks that Google Mail is trying to use the Washington Post's cert, which likely means something locally on your computer is caching a cert and reusing it on other sites. I cannot think of a good reason for this to be occurring.

Comment: @music2myear Since the problem occurs simultaneously in multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome) and similarly resolves simultaneously, it can't be a browser plugin or add-on. (Can it?) That said, I've got no unusual add-ons installed...

Comment: That's a good point. Router or AP issue?

Comment: We've got lots of machines in the house in the same home network; it's only one computer in particular that's having this problem.